# StretchBlt is too slow, anyway faster?

Tags: performance, gdi, stretchblt

I'm using StretchBlt to draw a resized real-time video.

```
 ::SetStretchBltMode(hDC, HALFTONE);
        ::StretchBlt(hDc, 0, 0, 1225, 689, hwNd, 0, 0, 1364, 768, SRCCOPY);
```

However, the StretchBlt api is too slow. It's take about 100ms on my computer each time StretchBlt is executed. Is there any other API or any way to improve the speed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using HW accelerated video processing:
Read more on [IDirectXVideoProcessor::VideoProcessBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Unfortunately, this is a wide topic but you can read online and find samples on how to use it.